# iterator.remove() deletes object from database

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm traversing through a list of objects using iterator.

```
    List<FormQuestion> questions = regMetadata.getFormQuestions();
    Iterator<FormQuestion> iter = questions.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        FormQuestion question = iter.next();
        //if invalid question, delete from list
        if(question.getModuleType().intValue() == -1) {
            iter.remove();
        } 
    }
```

`iter.remove()` is deleting the object from DB too. Is there any way to delete the object only from this list(questions) and not from the database? I'm using Hibernate & MySQL.

Comment: Hard to give an explanation with the little info provided but if I had to guess i would say that you probably have Cascading activated on the OneToMany relation and the Entity is not detached.

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't change the contents of a persistent class unless you actually want to save them. Create a separate object, maybe even a separate class, and then copy the data you need to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd filter the questions, writing them to a new `List`:

```
List<FormQuestion> questionsAll = regMetadata.getFormQuestions();
List<FormQuestion> questions = new ArrayList<>();
for (FormQuestion question : questionsAll) {
    // add to the list, unless invalid
    if (question.getModuleType().intValue() != -1) {
        questions.add(question)
    } 
}
```

Also, I use for-each loop instead of an `Iterator`. You can even rewrite it too streams too.

Comment: I have tried this solution before; it gives me another kind of problem.
StackTrace - 
{A collection with cascade=\"all-delete-orphan\" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.dyulok.dewa.model.register.RegistrationMetadata.formQuestions; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade=\"all-delete-orphan\" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance}

I want to return the list after deleting. If I follow this solution, it is throwing the above exception

Comment: Then you might need to *detach* the entities before doing anything with them. That's something like an `EntityManager.detach(object)` call for those  `FormQuestion` -s. It depends on your hibernate version too.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is managed by hibernate. You should first detach your list from persistence context and then you can remove from list without removing it from database. I think that picture here can help you. http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed